# How to insert records into existing HBase table using the Spark Streaming & Phoenix

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming, apache-phoenix

I am pushing data to HBase table "demo" using RestAPI. I want to save data to the same HBase table "demo" using spark streaming and phoenix, so that the table can hold data from RestAPI and stream workflow.
I read few posts on the internet and users recommended to create a table / view mapped to an existing HBase table i.e. "demo".

I created a table in phoenix as "demo" and able to insert streaming record into it, but what I have observed that HBase now had 2 table known as "DEMO" and "demo". Stream data is inserted into "DEMO" and RestAPI data inserts into "demo".

I want Stream and RestAPI data into a single HBase table, i.e. "demo".
How do I achieve it.